# Azure WebApp throws 502 page error when trying to access over xyz.azurewebsites.net

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I am currently building a backend for a website. I use Java/Spring boot to build my backend and I am trying to host it on Azure. I connected my main Branch from GitHub, so every time we merged into main, the changes were live. I hosted it for several weeks without any problems. All of a sudden the application stopped working and we couldn't reach it (Although Azure says it is up and running). If I try to reach my backend, it takes forever to load and eventually I'll either get an 502 Http Error or "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.". I checked, the problem is not that we maxed out our subscription/service-plan.
I started the application locally, which worked fine. That led me to the conclusion, that the problem must be Azure, but there are no Errors shown whatsoever. I have no idea how to fix the problem and I didn't find any solutions anywhere.
Maybe you can help me. Thanks in advance

Julius

Comment: Just in case you haven't already I must give the classic IT advice of restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything try restarting the app as @Josh Van de Walle mentioned if that does't work then here are few workarounds that you can try :-

There is a feature in Azure Website called Azure Auto Healing. Application issues such as clusters of bad status codes, slow requests or excess memory consumption we can use AutoHeal which ties a trigger to an action to automate .

Here is an example you can take a look at:-

```
<system.webServer>
    <monitoring>
        <triggers>
        
            <!-- Triggers when you have "count" responses matching the configured status within "timeInterval" amount of time -->
            <statusCode>
                <add statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" win32StatusCode="0" count="10" timeInterval="00:00:30"/>
            </statusCode>
            
            <!-- Triggers when you have "count" number of requests within "timeInterval" amount of time -->
            <requests count="1000" timeInterval="00:10:00"/>

            <!-- Triggers when you have "count" number of requests that take "timeTaken" within "timeInterval" amount of time -->
            <slowRequests timeTaken="00:00:45" count="20" timeInterval="00:02:00" />

            <!-- Triggers when your worker process reaches "privateBytesInKB" kilobytes of private set -->
            <memory privateBytesInKB="800000"/>    
                    
        </triggers>

        <!-- Performs an overlapping recycle of the worker process when a trigger fires -->
        <actions value="Recycle"/>
    </monitoring>
</system.webServer>
```

Another workaround that you can try checking the logs from your Kudu Console by navigating to `D:\home\LogFiles\` from `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to make sure what the reason is and work accordingly.

Also make sure you are adding `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` setting in your app service:

```
WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Configure Azure Auto-Healing for your Azure Web Sites](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/10/configure-azure-auto-healing-azure-web-sites/#:%7E:text=%20Configure%20Azure%20Auto-Healing%20for%20your%20Azure%20Web,from%20unexpected%20behavior.%20You%20set%20a...%20More%20)
2. [Use a TLS/SSL certificate in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code)